# jquery performance issues by enable drag & drop for new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, drag-and-drop

I've a small webapplication that works with some drag / drop functionality. Just imagine a small order system in which you can say order 1 (draggable) will be done by employee 2 (droppable). That works fine. BUT:

Every 20sec. I ask the database via AJAX for new orders. These new orders will also be draggable. In case that another college has given an order to en employee the list of orders for every employee is also no loaded. To enable drag / drop after the ajax request I had to run:

```
$('.order').draggable({
..
});
```

and

```
$('.employee').dropable({
..
});
```

So the jquery function walks every 20 secunds through the hole DOM. After 10-15 minitues the app becomes very slow. Do you have an idea how to ingrease that process? Is it possible to give an absolute statement that every .order class is draggable even if this element will be create after the first registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @ Jonas your great idea did it!

You can use the classes `ui-droppable` and `ui-draggable` for that job

```
$('.order').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    if ( !element.hasClass('ui-droppable')) {

    element.droppable({
    ...
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the elements that are already on the page become draggable over and over again.
I think a solution would be to assign a class to those that already have it:

```
$('.order').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    if ( !element.hasClass('event-already-attached')) {
        element.addClass('event-already-attached').draggable({

        })
    }
});
```

Comment: this could be a good idea! I will try and give a resonse! Thanks!